# How to deploy "quickstart-jekyll-zurb" to heroku

Tags: heroku, zurb-foundation, config, jekyll

I've cloned this repo:
https://github.com/lvillani/quickstart-jekyll-zurb

I got it working locally no problem.
I added a Procfile with the following:

```
web: bundle exec jekyll serve -P $PORT
```

Heroku accepts the bundle no problem.
But the server crashes when trying to load a page.
The first problem I had was that it was trying to render a misformated vendor page.
I fixed that by adding this to _config.yml:

```
exclude:
    - "vendor/bundle/ruby
```

But now my app.scss file can't `@import "foundation/settings";`.
Here is the relevant portion of the Heroku logs.

```
"2014-10-16T19:56:05.366451+00:00 app[web.1]:       Generating... 
2014-10-16T19:56:05.361060+00:00 app[web.1]: Configuration file: /app/_config.yml
2014-10-16T19:56:06.277480+00:00 app[web.1]:   Conversion error: There was an error converting 'asset/app.scss'.
2014-10-16T19:56:06.277526+00:00 app[web.1]: jekyll 2.1.1 | Error:  File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/settings.
2014-10-16T19:56:06.277529+00:00 app[web.1]: Load path: /app/_vendor/foundation/scss
```

Everything works fine locally, so I assume this is a Heroku configuration issue but I don't know enough about Heroku to begin to know where to look.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to run a `make setup`.

Note that your jekyll is 2.1.1 and current version is 2.4.

Comment: I did run make setup, which is how I got it working locally.
I tried removing the version restriction from the Gemfile and got a slightly different error that amounted to the same thing.